# how to extract the first character in Python

Tags: python

Good afternoon,
I have issue I want extract the first character before ',' from my input file and put inside new list.

my input file like:

```
[Afghanistan,Kabul

Albania,Tirana

Andorra,Andorra la Vella

Angola,Luanda

Antigua and Barbuda,St Johns

Argentina,Buenos Aires

Armenia,Yerevan

Australia,Canberra

Austria,Vienna

Azerbaijan,Baku

Bahamas,Nassau

Bahrain,Manama

Bangladesh,Dhaka

Barbados,Bridgetown

Belarus,Minsk

Belgium,Brussels

Belize,Belmopan

Benin,Porto Novo, Cotonou

Bhutan,Thimphu]
```

I tried this

```
with open (inputCc, 'r') as myfile_cc:
     my_string = myfile_cc.readlines()
     Cc = ('\n'.join(my_string))
     print (Cc)
country_list = []
country_list = [i.split(",")[0] for i in Cc]
print (country_list)
```

but does not working

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting as output, do you want the words before `,` like `['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Andorra', 'Angola', 'Antigua and Barbuda', ...]`?

Comment: Please show the desired output from your example input--it is not clear. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes I want before ,

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one. I found the solve for my problem.

```
    with open (inputCc, 'r') as myfile_cc:
    lines = myfile_cc.readlines()
    countryList = []                     # countryList

    for line in lines:
        split = line.split(',')                       
        split = [split[0], ','.join(split[1:])]
        countryList.append(split[0])
        capiatalList.append(split[1].strip('\n'))
```